# Find().find() doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

```
$(document).find('.AddressGroup').find('.toggle_container').slideDown("1000");
```

works in IE & FIREFOX but not in CHROME or OPERA. Why?

Answer (score 1):

try `body`

```
$('body').find('.AddressGroup').find('.toggle_container').slideDown("1000");
```

or better yet just

```
$('.AddressGroup .toggle_container').slideDown("1000");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.AddressGroup .toggle_container').slideDown(1000);
```